# How to call methods of an object defined in one function in another?

Tags: python, oop

**Essentially what I want to do is this: **

call line1.draw_shape(), line2.draw_shape()... etc inside of the draw_window function so that lines can be drawn above the background. Without the background, the lines are drawn fine when draw_shape is called inside of shape_generation.

I will be having a player rectangle drawn onto the screen that moves around later on, so I need a background to be drawn first in order to update all pixels on the screen, so that the player doesn't turn into a long snake.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1050, 630
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("game")
FPS = 30
GREY = (15, 15, 15)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
VEL = 5

class line:
    def __init__(self, lineX, lineY, dimensions):
        
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        
        if self.dimensions[2] == 1:
            self.lineY = lineY - HEIGHT//3
            self.lineX = lineX
        
        elif self.dimensions[2] == 2:
            self.lineX = lineX - HEIGHT//3
            self.lineY = lineY
        else:
            self.lineX = lineX
            self.lineY = lineY
            
    def draw_shape(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLUE, [self.lineX, self.lineY, self.dimensions[0], self.dimensions[1]] )

def shape_generation():
    LINE_DIMENSIONS = ((10, HEIGHT // 3, 1 ), (HEIGHT // 3, 10, 0), (10, HEIGHT // 3, 0), (HEIGHT // 3, 10, 2)) #NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
    line0 = line(WIDTH // 5, HEIGHT // 3, random.choice(LINE_DIMENSIONS))
    line1 = line((WIDTH // 5) * 2, HEIGHT // 3, random.choice(LINE_DIMENSIONS))
    line2 = line((WIDTH // 5) * 3, HEIGHT // 3, random.choice(LINE_DIMENSIONS))
    line3 = line((WIDTH // 5) * 4, HEIGHT // 3, random.choice(LINE_DIMENSIONS))
    line4 = line(WIDTH // 5, (HEIGHT // 3) * 2, random.choice(LINE_DIMENSIONS))
    line5 = line((WIDTH // 5) * 2, (HEIGHT // 3) * 2, random.choice(LINE_DIMENSIONS))

    
    
    line0.draw_shape()
    line1.draw_shape()
    line2.draw_shape()
    line3.draw_shape()
    line4.draw_shape()
    line5.draw_shape()
  
def draw_window():
    WIN.fill(GREY)
    #This is where I would like the walls to be drawn.
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    shape_generation()
    
    run = True
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
              
        draw_window()
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ive tried drawing the lines without a background. This means that a moving object causes the screen to be filled with that colour, as the pixels are not updated afterwards. It also means that whenever the lines positions are generated again, the previous lines remain as the surface pixels arn't updated to return to the background colour.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach is to have an object that is the line and update its coordinates when necessary instead of updating the whole display?

Comment: Put your line0->line5 objects in a list. Return that list from *shape_generation()*. Pass a reference to that list to *draw_window()*